# How to make Nginx HLS application pull RTMP on request

Tags: nginx, ffmpeg, http-live-streaming, rtmp

This is my situation: I want to use Nginx to serve streams over HTTP using HLS. The thing is, I want the HLS streams to be generated/started when I get a request for them.

I can successfully achieve this behavior with RTMP, as I have the following config file

```
application myApp {
  live on;    
  exec_pull myScript.sh $app $name;
  exec_kill_signal term;
}
```

In my `myScript.sh` file I have something like this:

```
ffmpeg -i sourceLink.m3u8 -codec copy -bsf:a aac_adtstoasc -f flv rtmp://localhost/$APP/$NAME;
```

So that when I request `rtmp://myAddress/myApp/someLink` it works perfectly.

However, I want to stream HLS instead of RTMP. I have seen other solutions that do this by having an application that starts the RTMP module and pushes it to the HLS application. However, what I want is that when I recieve a request for an HLS stream THEN the RTMP is started (which starts the FFmpeg), and as soon as the requests for the stream are over the RTMP stops receiving requests and thus stops the FFmpeg.

Here is my config file with what I have tried so far:

```
application myHLSApp {
  live on;
  pull rtmp://localhost:1935/myApp/someLink name=test static;
  # Turn on HLS
  hls on;
  hls_path /mnt/hls/;
  hls_fragment 3;
  hls_playlist_length 60;
  # disable consuming the stream from nginx as rtmp
  deny play all;
}
```

My main objective is to start the FFmpeg in `myScript.sh` ONLY when it is needed to then stream that incoming file as HLS from my machine. Any ideas?

Thanks a lot for the help!